# TFS building Xamarin.iOS fails to create ipa file

Tags: tfs, msbuild, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've followed the instructions on http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/configuring_tfs/ to configure a TFS server to build Xamarin.iOS apps. From VS on the server I can build the XiBHConnection project and generate an ipa file.

However, when I get TFS to run a build I don't see an ipa file in the output.

The appropriate configuration is selected and when built locally I get an ipa file.

How can I debug why TFS doesn't appear to using the Build Host? I've had a look in the generated logs and there's no obvious error message.

Thanks.

Comment: In case it's helpful, I abandoned this whole approach and setup a Jenkins build server. It was harder to get the source out of TFS but a much simpler build process.